# Using FullCalendar, how to add information to EventObject when eventReceive?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I've started discovering and using FullCalendar but I'm stuck with it.

What I want to do is a **ResourceTimeline** in **Month** view, with external event dragging (a left panel).

The subject later would be to have a modal when you drop an event, in order to choose if you want the event to be from 8am to 12pm, or afternoon from 12pm to 6pm.

So first, I'd like to do a simple eventReceive without modal, to see if I can update the event when it's dropped.

But it seems I can't, what do I do wrong ?

From what I can understand, it looks like when you drop an event in month view, the event in the param sent to eventReceive is modified.

```
eventReceive(info) {
  info.event.start = moment(info.event.start).add(8, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
  // var c = confirm('OK = morning, Cancel = aprem');
  // if (c) {
  //   console.log("morning !")
  // } else {
  //   console.log("afternoon !")
  // }
}
```

Events are very basic because I wanted to complete them whenever I drop them into the calendar

```
new Draggable(listofEvents, {
  itemSelector: '.draggable',
  eventData(event) {
    return {
      title: event.innerText,
      activite: event.dataset.activite,
      allDayDefault: false,
    }
  },
})
```

I even tried to force allDayDefault to false but it doesn't change a thing...

Here is the codepen of the project in its current state : https://codepen.io/nurovek/pen/zYYWGyX?editors=1000

*Sorry if my post lacks information, I'm not used to ask questions on SO. If it's lacking, I'll try to be more explicit if you ask me, of course !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), an event's public properties (such as "start", "end", title" etc) are **read-only**. Therefore to alter a property after the event is created you must run one of the ["set" methods](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-model).

So your idea will work if you use the `setDates` method:

```
eventReceive(info) {
  info.event.setDates(moment(info.event.start).add(8, 'hours').toDate(), info.event.end, { "allDay": false } )
  console.log(info.event);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyymawy?editors=1000

---

P.S. You might notice I also made a few other little changes to your CodePen, mainly to correct all the links to CSS and JS files, since it was generating all sorts of console errors. These errors were because links were wrong or simply referred to something non-existent, and for some reason you were also using files from two different versions of fullCalendar (4.3.0 and 4.3.1), which is never a good idea if you want to ensure full compatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was almost sure something of this kind existed, but I obviously overlooked. And thanks for updates in script imports, inconsistency from my side !